# Create a raster file from some data using Python

Tags: python, raster, tiff, qgis

I want to create a TIFF file from binary data, i.e., points in a given position (x,y) are either 0 or 1. Using Python, I want to map this points and a limited area around them into a raster file which can only have the values 0 or 1.
All I have found so far deals with an existing TIFF file that is read, its values are modified and saved again that same file. What I really want to do is to create a TIFF file from scratch. This is what I have so far:

```
def array2raster(newRasterfn,rasterOrigin,pixelWidth,pixelHeight,array):
  cols = array.shape[1]
  rows = array.shape[0]
  originX = rasterOrigin[0]
  originY = rasterOrigin[1]

  driver = gdal.GetDriverByName('GTiff')
  outRaster = driver.Create(newRasterfn, cols, rows, 1, gdal.GDT_Byte)
  outRaster.SetGeoTransform((originX, pixelWidth, 0, originY, 0, pixelHeight))
  outband = outRaster.GetRasterBand(1)
  outband.WriteArray(array)
  outRasterSRS = osr.SpatialReference()
  outRasterSRS.ImportFromEPSG(32629)
  outRaster.SetProjection(outRasterSRS.ExportToWkt())
  outband.FlushCache()
```

How do I specify the coordinates of a map point where I want to place a value (0 or 1)?

Comment: look into the rasterio library. it can take a numpy array and quickly make a georeferenced tif

Comment: Also: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve